# creating a food board in python

Tags: python, class, while-loop

I want to print out a menu in Python for practice. How could I turn this into a food board/table. I do not know how to make things look nice in Python, in terms of graphics.

This is what I have so far:

```
tzatziki = 17.00;
naan = 4.00;
roti = 7.50;
veggie_soup = 6.40;
potstickers = 10.01;
pineapple = 3.99;
total = 0.0;
DONE = False
print("
```

Comment: So is the goal to simple print out these prices, or do you want it to look like a nicely formatted table?

Comment: nicely formatted table if possible

Comment: Your code is going to be much more manageable if you put the data items into some kind of collection rather than a bunch of separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is a list of key/value pairs (e.g. Food/Price), you'll want to use a `dict` to store the name/price of each food item, and a `list` to store all the food items. This will make working with the data easier. You can then use the `pandas` library to represent this menu list as a DataFrame (table). You can learn more about `pandas` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create list of menu items/prices
menu = [{'food': 'tzatziki', 'price': 17.00},
        {'food': 'naan', 'price': 4.00},
        {'food': 'roti', 'price': 7.50}, ]

# Create dataframe from menu dictionary
menu_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(menu)

print(menu_dataframe)
```

Outputs:

```
       food  price
0  tzatziki   17.0
1      naan    4.0
2      roti    7.5
```